# C++ Process Monitor

Tags: c++, monitor

I'm trying to create a process monitor in linux that will tell me things about a process (whether it's running, how long it's been running... etc) in C++. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: probably you can use /proc/ file system. But a guru like monitor is never easy if it shall do ... etc.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend learning about `/proc` on linux.

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) is good place to start. Basically the proc filesystem gives you a way to get information about the system and kernel on Unix like OS's (including Linux).